# What does it mean if a domain is unlocked?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

A domain I'm interested in acquiring as its status showing as "Unlocked". It's due to expire in a couple of weeks.

What does the "unlocked" status mean? Am I more likely to be able to register the domain when/if it expires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unlocked" status just means that it can be transferred to a different registrar by its current owner; it won't help you to get it when it expires.